# creating Riot CMS Spring Java project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, content-management-system

The steps used for creating Riot CMS Spring Java project

1. I created Java dynamic project called newRiotDemo and put setup.xml
   (riotfamily.org/setup.xml) in WebContent
2. Then ran wget riotfamily.org/setup.xml && ant -f setup.xml terminal
3. Then refreshed project.put index.html in Webcontent.
4. no exception in console,no markers now but not getting my desired
   admin page while giving localhost:8080/newRiotDemo/riot     (Refernce-->http://www.riotfamily.org/docs/quickstart.html)

Can anyone help me on how to proceed further? Where should we include riot code obtained from https://github.com/riotfamily/riot/downloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,

I tried following commands in terminal==>

mkdir my-riot
  cd my-riot
  git clone git://github.com/riotfamily/riot.git

git clone git://github.com/riotfamily/riot-skeleton.git

cd riot

git checkout 9.0.x

ant install-release

cd ../riot-skeleton

git checkout 9.0.x & then ant war

**Output obtained**==> riot-skeleton.jar & riot-skeleton-mysystemloginname.war & classes folder in build folder

Then I imported the above riot-skeleton-mysystemloginname.war into eclipse & got localhost:8080/riot-skeleton-mysystemloginname/home/ page  in browser.

While logging in as admin,admin localhost:8080/riot-skeleton-mysystemloginname/riot/,am able to see Toolbar in Pets & home page too.                                                                                                                                                                                 **NB:-***If you face,"CSRF SECURITY ERROR" just put this code in riot-servlet.xml*:

```
        <override:properties ref="dwrController">
         <property name="configParams">
           <props>
          <prop key="crossDomainSessionSecurity">false</prop>
           </props>
           </property>
        </override:properties>
```

I hope that solution will be useful to someone.

Comment: Can you make clear what you're asking and whether this answer is actually a solution? If it is a solution to your original question then ask the new question separately.

Comment: Hi adamjansch,  I was half way to my goal for creating Riot CMS Spring Java project and had csrf security error.thats y included here

Comment: Hi,                                                               To solve this in "CSRF SECURITY ERROR" just put this code in riot-servlet.xml:

            <override:properties ref="dwrController">
                        <property name="configParams">
                                   <props>
                                               <prop
key="crossDomainSessionSecurity">false</prop>
                                   </props>
                        </property>
            </override:properties>

I hope that solution will be useful to someone.

Comment: It seems as though you've solved it. You should edit your answer to include the solution from that last comment, otherwise this answer might be removed for 'not being an answer'.